# Why ARP Response only when network adapter in promiscuous mode?

Tags: bridge, arp

In my home network (10.0.0.0/24) i want to deploy a network printer, without laying a cable from the switch to it. So i used a Raspberry Pi, that connects via Wifi to my wireless network and wired it's Ethernet port with the printer. The goal was to have something like a Wifi-Ethernet Bridge here...

```
RPi Ethernet IP (eth0): 10.0.0.32
RPi Wifi IP (wlan0): 10.0.0.31
Printer IP: 10.0.0.30
```

After playing around with tcpdump i found out, that the RPi is answering to ARP Requests from the Router (10.0.0.1), only when i had

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1
```

enabled. What is something i can understand reading the manpages. I tested this with simple pings from the router to the printer's IP.

Now, when i deleted the ARP Cache on the router without having tcpdump opened on the RPi somehow ARP Responses stopped working. So i was wondering why it starts to work again, as soon as i started tcpdump on the Pi. It turned out, that tcpdump is putting the WiFi Interface of the Raspberry Pi to promiscuous mode. In order to work properly i put the WiFi Interface of the Pi in permanent promiscuous mode

```
 ip link set wlan0 promisc on
```

and everything is working fine now, but since i have the Feeling that this solution "smells" i would like to know what's going on here and why proxy_arp isn't sufficient?

Additionally, since i have two network interfaces here, working on the same subnet, i made sure with some route policies, that only traffic to the printer is routed via eth0.

```
localhost ~ # ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  not from all to 10.0.0.30 lookup main
32765:  from all to 10.0.0.30 lookup print
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default


localhost ~ # ip route show table print
10.0.0.30 dev eth0  scope link
```

Comment: Why aren’t you bridging the two network interfaces? You tagged that keyword in your question, but you aren’t actually doing that. Get rid of all route rules and bridge the two interfaces.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention, that when i add the wifi Adapter to a bridge, the OS responds with Operation not supported (ip link set dev wlan0 master br0). I will investigate on that, since "real" bridging should be the way to go...

Comment: Only for reference: I haven't seen your question so I have made nearly the same [Is promiscuous mode needed for proxy arp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446795/243074).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are fundamentally two ways to do what you are trying to do: Routing and bridging.

Neither of those make use of `proxy_arp`. `proxy_arp` is a hack you can use if parts of your network think you are routing and other parts think you are bridging. It's a last resort you should only use when you have ruled out all other options.

My recommendation is you need to fully understand both the routing and bridging solution and understand why neither will work for you before you resort to `proxy_arp`.

Your usage case does not sound like one of those where `proxy_arp` would be necessary.

**Solving the problem with bridging**

WiFi uses MAC addresses at two layers of the stack. You will have a pair of MAC addresses for the endpoints like in wired Ethernet. And you will have a pair of MAC addresses indicating the endpoints of the wireless link.

Unfortunately the original WiFi standard assumed a specific pair of those four MAC addresses would always be identical, and that assumption is not true when bridging. So a newer standard called WDS was introduced to fix that.

So in order to configure bridging you need to ensure the hardware at both ends of your WiFi connection supports WDS and have it enabled. Next you need to revert those two `sysctl` changes that you made because those are not used for bridging.

Finally you need to configure a bridge on the Pi which combines the wired and wireless interfaces into a bridge. If you want the Pi to speak IP as well you configure that on the bridge interface not the underlying physical interfaces.

This is a bunch of things to configure and there is the risk that WDS is not supported by the hardware.

**Solving the problem with routing**

If you want to do routing you still need to revert the `proxy_arp` setting. The `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` setting is however correct for a routing setup.

On the Pi you need to configure the two network interfaces with different prefixes. The wireless which you have already configured with `10.0.0.0/24` you can probably leave as it is, since that part is already working.

The wired interface however you need to configure with another prefix. A possible choice is `10.0.1.0/24`. And you can assign `10.0.1.1` to the wired interface on the Pi.

The printer can either be configured with a static IP address such as `10.0.1.2` or you can let it be configured dynamically which require you to install a DHCP server on the Pi which hands out addresses in the `10.0.1.1` prefix.

Finally you need to tell your existing router about this new network by adding a routing table entry. In the configuration on your existing router add a routing table entry for the prefix `10.0.1.0/24` (alternatively written as `10.0.1.0/255.255.255.0`) with a gateway address of `10.0.0.31`. You need to ensure that the address `10.0.0.31` is somehow kept static, otherwise your routing table entry will become incorrect.

Comment: I had the exact Routing solution in place, but my goal was to stay in the same address range with all devices. I will check the bridging solution again but when i tested to add the wifi Adapter to a bridge ... "ip link set dev wlan0 master br0" ... it responds with Operation not supported. i will investigate on that.

Comment: i guess the solution is something like that https://serverfault.com/a/554663/345934

Comment: @ChristianEhrig Sounds like that might work. Personally I have always used the routing approach for such setups as I found that to be easier to configure than bridging over wireless.

Comment: @ChristianEhrig All Raspberry Pis does not support *WDS*. Devices supporting this have a supported command `set_wds_peer`. You will not find it with `sudo iw phy | grep set_wds_peer` on a RasPi.